# Guzzle can’t find its own files

Tags: php, guzzle, opentok

I want to run Guzzle on Xampp server, but when I try to run it, I get message:

> Fatal error: Class 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException' not found in D:\2 Workspace\5 Aptana\OpenTok\Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException.php on line 8

I need it as a part of PHP API for OpenTok project. I can't use composer, so I downloaded it manually, but it doesn't work. I think it can be something with `namespace` and `use`.

What should I do to get this working?

Comment: How does your autoload class looks like? Have you implemented a PSR-0 / PSR-4 or custom autoloader?

Comment: That was my real problem - I didn't use any autoload class, but tried to load files all at once. Thanks @cocheese for hint! I just didn't know about autoloaders in PHP at all.

Comment: @thorin86, you should add an accepted answer to your question so you can help others with the same problem :)